# How to catch user choice of jradiobutton in jpopupmenu?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jpopupmenu, jradiobutton

I have been able to show a popup menu in my frame and the menu items, a group of radio buttons may be navigated with the arrow keys. When the user presses Enter/Return the popup menu is no longer visible and I assume that it is possible to determine which button was chosen and assign an action.

```
    private static final JPopupMenu popupSyncTIR = new JPopupMenu();
    popupSyncTIR.setLabel("Sensor Synced to Clock");
    ButtonGroup grpTIR = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rbTIRMenuItem;
    rbTIRMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Sync TIR-A to clock");
    rbTIRMenuItem.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
    grpTIR.add(rbTIRMenuItem);
    popupSyncTIR.add(rbTIRMenuItem);
    rbTIRMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Sync TIR-B to clock");
    rbTIRMenuItem.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
    rbTIRMenuItem.setSelected(true);
    grpTIR.add(rbTIRMenuItem);
    popupSyncTIR.add(rbTIRMenuItem);
    rbTIRMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Sync TIR-C to clock");
    rbTIRMenuItem.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
    grpTIR.add(rbTIRMenuItem);
    popupSyncTIR.add(rbTIRMenuItem);
```

I have also implemented key mapping for the whole frame like this:

```
/**
 * alt-T period synch TIR sensor w/clock
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private static void registerSyncTIRAction() {
    javax.swing.Action tirSync = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            setTIRSensorSync();
        }
    };
    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_T,
            java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK);
    ((JComponent) contentPanel).getActionMap().put("TirSync", tirSync);
    ((JComponent) contentPanel).getInputMap(
            JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, "TirSync");

}

/** 
 * Show the TIR popup
 */
private static void setTIRSensorSync() {
    popupSyncTIR.show(pnlTIR, 10, 10); 
}
```

How do I determine what radio button was selected before the user pressed Enter?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the same as you would with radioButtons which are not in a menu :-) Use Actions:

```
Action actionA = new AbstractAction("Synch A to clock") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do stuff A
    }
};
JRadioButtonMenuItem buttonA = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(actionA);
Action actionB = new AbstractAction("Synch B to clock") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do stuff B
    }
};
JRadioButtonMenuItem buttonB = new JRadioButtonItem(actionB);
ButtonGroup ... // add buttons to group
JPopupMenu ... // add buttons to menu
```

Comment: Stupid question (sorry, bot in front of a pc at the mo) would the action event cause the popup to close or not? No reason for asking other they curiosity

Comment: not mouse or keyboard events implemented in the APIs, popup always closed (from Java1.4) without listener is added or not

Comment: Thank you, I've now used a radio button in *Java* for the first time. (I'm a bit new to Java...) All I need to do now is add a cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the result is still stored in the component's you added to the popup menu.

You need to implement a [PopupMenuListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/PopupMenuListener.html) to your popup and monitor `popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible` method.

When called, you will need to interrogate the components you had on the popup menu for the one that is selected.

If you still have a reference to them directly (ie with in the class context), you can access them directly.

The next best would be achieved by sub classing the popup menu.

```
public class ChoicesPopupMenu exends JPopupMenu {

    JRadioButtonMenuItem rbAClock;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rbBClock;
    JRadioButtonMenuItem rbCClock;

    // Construct the UI ...

    public boolean isAClockSelected() {
        return rbAClock.isSelected();
    }

    // Other selection checkers...

}
```

Alternatively, you could walk the component hierarchy of the `JPopupMenu`

```
public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
    JPopupMenu menu = (JPopupMenu)e.getSource();
    for (Component comp : menu.getComponents()) {
        if (comp instanceof JRadioButton) {
            JRadioButton rb = (JRadioButton)comp;
            if (rb.isSelected()) {
                // Figure out which one is selected...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ehh ... no, a popupMenuListener is not required.